# DataTemplateColumn requires 2 tabs to get to the content

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, focus

I have found a lot of articles on this issue, but none of them seem to work. I have 3 DataTemplateColumns, two with textboxes and one with a toggle button. Tabbing through first goes to the cell, then the content. I have tried MANY suggestions from other sites and my own inventions without any luck. I can get it to work on the first row, and when I add another, but add 2 at a time and it stops working. I hate. DataTemplate. Columns. Here is the class im using currently, utilizing a dependency property.

```
public class FocusAttacher
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FocusProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Focus", 
        typeof(bool), 
        typeof(FocusAttacher), 
        new PropertyMetadata(false, FocusChanged));

    public static bool GetFocus(DependencyObject d)
    {
        return (bool)d.GetValue(FocusProperty);
    }

    public static void SetFocus(DependencyObject d, bool value)
    {
        d.SetValue(FocusProperty, value);
    }

    public static void FocusChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            ((UIElement)sender).Focus();
        }
    }
```

### }

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Some Value"
                                    MinWidth="30"
                                    Width=".02*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding SomeBinding, 
                                                ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, 
                                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                 IsReadOnly="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                               AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, 
                                               Path=DataContext.IsReadOnly}"
                                 Style="{StaticResource SomeStyle}"
                                 customControls:FocusAttacher.Focus="True"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

And oddly enough, this is only working for the text boxes and not the toggle button in my third column. ARGH!!!!!

Edit: Here is the DataTemplate for the Button. It is setup as a custom control strictly for style and trigger purposes. It is a Button with a controltemplate containing a border and contentpresenter.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <customControls:MetroButton cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action RemoveGroup($dataContext)]"
           Width="15"
           Height="15"
           IsTabStop="False"
           Focusable="False"
           MouseOverBackground="LightGray">
           <Button.Visibility>
           <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BoolsToVisibilityAndConverter}">
                                    <Binding Path="IsReadOnly"
                                                 Converter="{StaticResource BooleanInverterConverter}" 
                                                 RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}"/>
                                    <Binding Path="IsDeletable"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </Button.Visibility>
                            <TextBlock Text="-"
                                       Focusable="False"
                                       Margin="0 -6 0 0" />

                        </customControls:MetroButton>
                        </DataTemplate>
```

EDIT: Adding the button custom control.

```
<Button x:Class="Beacon.FlexCare.UI.CustomControls.MetroButton"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:customControls="clr-namespace:Beacon.FlexCare.UI.CustomControls"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="300"
    MouseEnter="MetroButtonDefinition_MouseEnter"
    MouseLeave="MetroButtonDefinition_MouseLeave"
    customControls:FocusAttacher.Focus="True"
    x:Name="MetroButtonDefinition">
<Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop"
                Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Focusable"
                Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border x:Name="rectangle"

                            BorderThickness="1.3"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="White"
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <Border.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                                <Setter Property="Focusable"
                                        Value="False" />
                            </Style>
                        </Border.Style>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                          RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                          OpacityMask="White">
                        </ContentPresenter>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed"
                                 Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background"
                                    Value="#005285" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                                 Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                    Value="Gray" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="Transparent" />
    </Style>
</Button.Style>
```

Please help me before I shoot myself. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For me this works:

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

Comment: YOU ARE GETTING A CHRISTMAS CARD, AND A BOX OF CHOCOLATES. Still doesn't work for the toggle button though.

Comment: What's the DataTemplate of this Column?

Comment: Try `<customControls:MetroButton IsTabStop="False" Focusable="False" ...` for this Control too. If this doesn't help you have to show your MetroButton XAML for further help.

Comment: I have posted the XAML for the metrobutton. They way things are currently configured, it is skipping over the button but still tabbing to what appears to be the cell.